# Giant animal mounts in high fantasy

Tags: fiction, fantasy

I am creating a fantasy world with high presence of magic. I wanted to use large versions normal animals as mounts used like horses in war and normal life. My explanation as to why there are larger versions normal animals is that sorcerers have used magic to alter their anatomy to become larger and began mass breading of them. It can also be done to birds so you can have an air force made of giant eagles, falcon, hawks, and more. Does this sound like a good idea? Is my explanation of it plausible? Any tips for improving it?

Comment: Hi Ninja and welcome to writers. Unfortunately this question is not a good fit for our format. "good idea" is not objective category and so we can only offer opinions, not factually grounded answers. Please take the tour to see how things work around here: https://writers.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Try [WB: SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), also, [Square-Cube Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law) and [Argentavis Magnificens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentavis), [Wing loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_loading) can also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Magic can make anything plausible. The key is to think about consequences. If magic is commonly used to enlarge animals, it won't only be used for war.  Will gaint oxen pull ploughs?  Giant sheep grow wool?  Giant rats infest barns, and require giant cats to keep them under control?

In thinking about how a technology  (and wide-spread magic use *is* a technology) affects the economy, the two most important things to consider are "who stands to gain because this technology exists?" and "who stands to suffer because this technology exists?"

Comment: Whereas, I'm thinking - how is that sustainable. What will those critters eat? Where are they going to find enough food?

Comment: That's easy. You feed the giant eagles with giant rabbits, and you feed the giant rabbits with giant grass, and oh dear, this giant grass has turned into an invasive species that is destroying our pastures and farmland.  Oops.

Comment: Magic is vast. Sorcerers could use magic to make animals larger when needed and return them to their original form when not needed. Why would they need to breed them at all if they can use their magic to enlarge them? As the comments above said, there will be consequences when having large animals around. Also, why the need of large animals? Do they have to fight with giants or what? Wouldn't a normal animal be enough if they can rely on their magical powers? Having a large animal or a normal one, won't really make much difference if the animal doesn't have anything special about it.